# Why are my screens closing slowly rather than as they did yesterday and always before?

Tags: windows-7, windows

Today for the first time my screens do not close quickly but fade. I have altered nothing on my settings. What is causing this and how do I get back to the previous close speed

Comment: [screens](http://res1.windows.microsoft.com/resbox/en/6.3/main/ead9297a-050b-4c9e-acd1-51f8b72e677d_12.png).  [windows](http://res1.windows.microsoft.com/resbox/en/windows%207/main/21b7b862-a70d-43aa-a281-e00c38a8078d_49.jpg).  You mean windows, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

This could be another MS update bug.

A few days ago I installed a fresh copy of Windows 7 including all updates - same result. Slow fade on launching applications/explorer. As a temporary "fix", it might help to use ccleaner or registry cleaner.

At the office I have another pc with the same problem starting at the start of the March - there was no problems before. I used CCleaner on it and it seems fine.

Comment: Hi @aezau, welcome to SuperUser. I appreciate your first language is not English but people would welcome a little more care since answers here are used as a reference for the future.